# error: no matching function for call to ‘ope::ope()

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

```
 #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        class ope
        {
            private: int real, imag;
            public:
            ope(int r, int i){
                    real=r;
                    imag=i;
         }
        ope operator + (ope const &obj) //operator overloading
            {   ope temp;
                temp.imag = imag + obj.imag;
                temp.real = real + obj.real;
                return temp;
            }
            void show()
            {
                cout << "Result : " << real << " + i"  << imag << endl;//print complex numbers
            }
        };
        int main()
        {
            ope f1(2,5) , f2(7,6);
            ope f3 = f1+f2;
            f3.show();
        return 0;
        }
```

I am new in programming and I tried to use operator overloading but I got this error can anyone help me? In this code, I am trying to print complex numbers using operator overloading.

Comment: `class op` I guess it is a typo. -> `class ope`

Comment: Nope I type wrong here sorry let me edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
ope temp;
```

requires a parameterless constructor (a.k.a default constructor), but `ope` has only a constructor that requires two parameters. You might as well use the parameterized constructor here:

```
ope operator + (ope const &obj) //operator overloading
{   
    ope temp(real + obj.real, imag + obj.imag);

    return temp;
}
```

---

... or define a default constructor

```
class ope {
// ...
public:
  ope(): real(0), imag(0) {}
// ...
```